# AngularJS: Record inserts beautifully but browser won't "go home" after

Tags: angularjs

I am inserting a record into a SharePoint custom list from an AngularJS Service -- works great! When the promise is returned, I just want the browser to go to the default route because a SharePoint workflow will take over after insert.

The browser just stays on the form when I use the following in my controller:

```
var SystemDownController = function($scope, $location, SharePointJSOMService){
    $scope.addNewSystemDown = function($event){
        $event.preventDefault();
        $.when(SharePointJSOMService.addSystemDown($scope.frm))
            .done(function(id){
                $location.path('/');
            })
            .fail(function(err){
                console.info(JSON.stringify(err)); 
            });
        };
}; // end SystemDownController

SystemDownController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', 'SharePointJSOMService'];

angular.module('appITI').controller('SystemDownController', SystemDownController);
```

Comment: did you try $scope.$apply() after $location.path()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would better use native Angular promise implementation:

```
$q.when(SharePointJSOMService.addSystemDown($scope.frm))
.then(function(id) {
    $location.path('/');
}, function(err) {
    console.info(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Or if you still want to use jQuery promises then you should trigger digest loop yourself:

```
.done(function(id) {
    $location.path('/');
    $scope.$apply();
})

$scope.$apply();
```